# Unfortunately app has stopped in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new in Android.I get "Unfortunately app has stopped" when i run following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn;
EditText edit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_click);
    btn.setOnClickListener(onClickList);

}
private OnClickListener onClickList= new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    btn.setText(edit.getText());

    }
};
```

Comment: since you are new, here's some advice about this forum - post the stack trace of the error (from the `logcat` output) - you will get better answers and people will treat you better. good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Wrong:

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.test_click);
```

### Issue:

You are trying to find views before setting layout to Activity. So call `setContentView()` first and then you can find whichever views you want.

### Correct:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.test_click);
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are accessing views from current Activity before setting layout for Activity .Call `setContentView` before accessing views from xml as:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_click);  // set layout here

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
    btn.setOnClickListener(onClickList);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `findViewById()` after you call `setContentView()`.